# Cannot make program-generated texture appear on an OpenGL Sphere

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, 3d, textures

I want to label a 3D OpenGL object (a sphere) with a text label, in a MacBook application. I have decided to create a bitmap with the text, and use that to create an OpenGL texture which will be bound to the sphere. Mac is moving away from GLUT so my code is GLUT-free. The basics all work, but I am unable to get the text to wrap the sphere: it is as if none of the texture mapping code were there. Here is the code from the window controller, which I use to create the texture:

```
- (GLuint) makeDecalFor: (PasteurCard*) aRole
          withCardColor: (PasteurColor*) cardColor
{
    assert(aRole != nil);
    assert(cardColor != nil);
    NSString *const roleName = [aRole name];

    assert(context_ != nil);
    [context_ makeCurrentContext];  // context_ is an NSOpenGLContext*

    GLuint textureID[2];
    textureID[0] = textureID[1] = 0;
    NSColor *const textColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    NSFont *const font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize: 26];
    NSRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
        frame.size.height = 128;
        frame.size.width = 128;
    NSPoint textLocation;
        textLocation.x = 40;
        textLocation.y = 48;
    NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = nil;

    NSDictionary *attribs =    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    textColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -3.0], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName,
                                    font, NSFontAttributeName,
                                    nil];

    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: frame.size];
    assert(image != nil);
    [image lockFocus];
    [[cardColor cocoaColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect: frame];
    assert(textColor != nil);
    [textColor set];
    [roleName drawAtPoint: textLocation withAttributes: attribs];
    bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect: frame];
    assert(bitmap != nil);

    // at this point the bitmap looks fine

    [image unlockFocus];


    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
    glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );   // or GL_DECAL

    glGenTextures(1, &textureID[0]);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID[0] );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    const BOOL bitmapHasAlpha = [bitmap hasAlpha];   // yes, it does
    glTexImage2D(
                 GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_RGBA,
                 bitmap.size.width,
                 bitmap.size.height,
                 0,
                 bitmapHasAlpha ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 [bitmap bitmapData]
                 );

    assert(textureID[0] > 0);
    return textureID[0];
}
```

I check OpenGL return codes religiously (I omitted these checks from the above code for brevity). The `glGenTextures` call returns a reasonable value (1 for the first one and successive small integers for subsequent objects.)

`GL_LIGHTING` is enabled, and I know that I'll eventually have to play around with `GL_MODULATE` and `GL_DECAL` when I get to the next step. I was worried that having `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` enabled was problematic, but it works O.K. with the stub.

If I replace this code with a stub that reads in a simple RGB image (which also has an alpha channel, FWIW) and produces a texture, it works: I get a canned texture nicely wrapped on the sphere. That suggests that my error is in the above code. I've culled related posts here and have carefully heeded the advice that seems to apply to my case, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

OSX Yosemite 10.10.1, MacBook Pro, Xcode 6.1.1, OpenGL 2.1 INTEL-10.0.86

Comment: Can you try setting the internal format to `GL_RGB` as well if there is no alpha? I know it's legal to specify RGB data for RGBA textures in newer versions of OpenGL, but I'm not completely sure for OpenGL 2.1.

Comment: Thanks, Reto. I've tried this but it makes no difference. I'm confident the image has an alpha channel. Right now I'm methodically trying a large combination of settings, including playing with other parameters, mainly glPixelStorei and glTexParameter stuff.